# Orthogonal parameterization

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving, coordinate-systems, parametric

Consider the function
$$f(a,b,c,d):=\frac{\left(a^*\right)^2b^2-\left(b^*\right)^2a^2+\left(c^*\right)^2d^2-\left(d^*\right)^2c^2}{a^*a+c^*c}$$

With complex parameters $a,b,c$ and $d$

Now find any explicit $a(t), b(t), c(t)$ and $d(t)$, with $t$ is a arbitrary real number, such that $$f(t):=f\left(a(t),b(t),c(t),d(t)\right)=\text{const}$$

is constant with respect to $t$. That means $\frac{df}{dt}=0$ and at least one of them is not constant.

Finally I want to have a 8 dimensional "surjective" parametrization $a(p_1,...,p_8),b(p_1,...,p_8),c(p_1,...,p_8)$ and $d(p_1,...,p_8)$ such that $$f(p_1,...,p_8)=f(\vec p):=f\left(a(\vec p),b(\vec p),c(\vec p),d(\vec p)\right)$$ with $\frac{df}{dp_1}=...=\frac{df}{dp_7}=0$ but $\frac{df}{dp_8}\neq 0$.

The $p_i$ might be real. Instead of that 4 complex $p_i$ would also be fine.

As an example, consider $d(x_1,...,x_8):=\sum_{i=1}^8 x_i^2$. For this, that could be done using the polar coordinates. With seven angles, which let $g$ invariant and one radius which does not.

Comment: I assume you mean that at least one of these is non-constant. Otherwise, just choose $a(t) = A, b(t) = B,$ etc.

Comment: Yes! I am looking for a non trivial solution

Comment: Doesn't $a(t) = \sin t, c(t) = \cos t, b(t) = d(t) = t$ work? The denominator's always $1$, and the first and second halves of the numerator are always zero. Or is $t$ not supposed to be a real variable, but a complex one?

Comment: Yes $t$ can be real valued.

Comment: @John do you know a solution with $f(t)\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Nope...but I haven't really thought about it for more than a minute or two.

Comment: @John Do you think there is a possibility to find a 8 dim parameterization, such that $f(p_1,...,p_8)$ is invariant under $p_1,..,p_7$ ? But $\frac{df}{dp_8}\neq 0$ This would be the final result I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your extended question correctly (and the "polar coords" example helps here), I can propose the following:

$$
f(x_1, \ldots, x_8) = x_8
$$
This has seven partials that are all zero, and an eighth that is not. The function $f$ is invariant under seven independent translations, but not invariant under the 8th.

What I *don't* understand is how this is related to the first half of the problem, however, where there seems to be a curve in 4-space defined by $a(t), \ldots, d(t)$.

Comment: I edit my question in order to make my problem more clear. I need the transformation $R^8\to C^4$ in such a way I described above.